# How to convert all Google Docs in a folder into PDFs?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, pdf-generation, google-workspace

I've created a simple Google Apps script to convert all Google Documents in a folder in my Drive into PDFs and save them to the same folder, which works:

```js
function convertDocsToPDF() {
 
  var folderId = "asdf";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  var invoices = folder.getFiles();
  
  while (invoices.hasNext()) {
    var invoice = invoices.next();
    var id = invoice.getId();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var PDFblob = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    var PDF = DriveApp.createFile(PDFblob);
    PDF.moveTo(file.getParents().next());
  }
}
```

I wrote this to test out the conversion, but want to integrate it into a longer script. The longer script creates the invoices from a template by replacing `##TextToReplace##` styled fields with data I pull from spreadsheets.

When I try to integrate the `convertDocsToPDF()` functionality, the PDFs all look like the template, not the invoice. When I look at the invoice document when the script is done, it looks correct with all the fields replaced with the correct data, but the PDF just looks like a copy of the template.

Is there a lag between when my script edits the invoice and when it is saved in my Drive such that the PDF conversion is seeing the invoice before the replaced text?

Comment: I've had this same problem and found that it's useful to call `Document.saveAndClose()` before generating the pdf.  I believe this flushes the changes as you suggest may be the problem.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee, thank you for your comment/response. saveAndClose() seems promising and I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It takes time for an edit to be pushed to the server.

This delay may be very small, but a script will be faster.

#### Things you can try:

- Use [`Document.saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) as suggested by @Aaron Dunigan AtLee.
- Use [`Utilities.sleep()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) at strategic places in your script.
- Make a loop to generate the invoices first, and then convert to pdf.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm going to give both saveAndClose() and sleep() a try. The last option might work, but since I'm creating the PDFs in the same loop as the invoices (so that I can use some of the same values I pull from my spreadsheet to complete the invoice as I do for creating the PDF and the email draft), I'm going to skip this one as I'd have to somehow re-associate those values from the invoice with the PDF/email draft.

Comment: `Document.saveAndClose()` did the trick.